# Unable to read typings for "es6-shim"

Tags: angularjs, npm-install, typescript-typings

Hi while trying the "npm install" command I'm gettin this error:

> Unable to read typings for "es6-shim". You should check the entry paths in "es6-shim.d.ts" are up to date
>
> caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/9807d9b701f58be068cb07833d2b24235351d052/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts"
>
> caused by connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.36:443

typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you access that URL yourself in a browser?

Comment: @RichardSzalay yes, I can

Answer (score 1):

`10.10.34.36:443` means `https://raw.githubusercontent.com` is filtered/censored in your country. But there's a better way to manage it these days. The new recommendation according to TS is to use NPM to manage your Typings:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/core-js
```

It's the same as installing a normal npm package, but it has `@types/` at the beginning. You can find the installed package in the `node_modules\@types` folder.